# How to Send Object to EJB through Remote Interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Hello i have a Web Application Which has Class Library which with remote interfaces, EJB module with beans and Struts 2 web application. Whenever i try to send a custom object to EJB through Remote Interface i get following Exception.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446393 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class newp.Employee  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225.couldNotFindClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can not pass any custom object. Classes implements serializable. IT works fine when retrieve objects from ejb through interface. Can anybody help?

Comment: Reading something about "couldNotFindClass", I guess your application doesn't have the class of the sent object in its classpath.

Comment: I have my entities in both EJB module and struts 2 web application. Do i need to include entities in my class library too? By the way this happens only when i send data to ejb. Structs action can receive data from ejb without any issues..

Comment: @LakshithaRanasinghe how did you solve your problem, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

as @Spyros k said you should first include your custom classes structure into your server. This means simply that you must put CustomObject.java classes of your own into your server. You should know that sending object by EJB is not sending exact class object , it's just a reference for server which is needed to be cast a class type. All of the Java standard classes are in server because of JVM but if you have a custom class sending a reference is not enough and you must have the class structure on the other side to cast the received reference .
So in server side you should have something like this :

```
YourCustomObject obj = (YourCustomObject) EjbObject.returnRefernce();
```

If you don't have YourCustomObject.java class on the other side so how could you cast to it? 
I suggest read about RMI to find more about this structure.

Comment: I have exactly same entities in both ejb and my struts application. I have started building my app again from scratch. First time i used a Remote Class Library but second time included remote interfaces in both sides. Now i am able to send some objects through the interface but i get the same error for some object types. Those objects are directly generated from my database using netbeans. :( Something wrong with database structure?

Comment: Sorry for late response but for the sake of science, what was the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The class newp.Employee should be included in the classpath of the Server side.
The server needs the class definition to deserialize the input.

Comment: Can u explain a little bit? New to ejb.. :( I have included all the entities in both struts 2 application and ejb module..